# Error trying to use bluemix command line

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to upload a simple python code to an app that I created on Bluemix. I'm using Bluemix CLI, but I got the following error on any bluemix command:

```
exec: "cf": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you installed the `bluemix` command line, but not the `cf` command line interface.

`bluemix` cli uses the `cf` cli internally, so you need to install `cf` as well.

You can find the latest version here:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Comment: Thank you Alex! That was my issue, I needed to install `cf` command line interface.